# Is it possible to run dotfuscator from command line without opening GUI application

Tags: obfuscation

i am looking for obfuscator tool to secure the assembly. and i need to do reverse enginnering on that obfuscated assembly to invoke methods.
right now i tried with dotfuscator tool which is integrated with VS 2005,2008. 
and i follow following steps.
1. Make obfuscated assembly using GUI tool.
2. Import in reflector.
3. i am able to see converted methods and variable name in reflector. 
4. After that i try out to access methods using converted name and its working fine.

i need to secure assembly even user can see method name using reflector but developer can do re-engineering on opfuscated assembly.

Is there any tool available to make secure assembly ???

and i want to run obfuscator tool from command line witout opening GUI application.

Comment: More specifically: - http://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/dotfuscator_documentation/Dotfuscator/Command_Line_Quick_Start.html - http://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/dotfuscator_documentation/Dotfuscator/Command_Line_Option_Summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the Command Line Option Summary in the [PreEmptive Dotfuscator Documentation](http://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/dotfuscator_documentation/Dotfuscator/webframe.html).

Answer (score 0):

To run Dotfuscator without opening Visual Studio, you need to purchase it. The Community Edition requires Visual Studio be open.